# How to stream mongo db data using spring boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am looking to find a way to stream Mongo DB response in spring boot.

Unfortunately I am getting all the references related to Node.js.

Isn't possible using java, spring boot?

Any suggestions to stream mongo db query results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *Java 8* (most currently used) you cannot map directly a mongodb stream to the Spring Boot output stream, you must to use the `StreamSupport.stream`

```
Stream<YourData> readData(...) {
    final MongoIterable<YourData> rs = myCollection.find(...)
            .projection(fields(...))
            .map(x -> new YourData(x));
    return StreamSupport.stream(rs.spliterator(), false);
}
```

Now, simply connect your stream to your controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/mydata")
public Stream<YourData> mydata(...) {
    return backend.readData(...);
}
```

Of course, you can do any `streaming` process to manipulate you data in a `streaming` way.

```
@RequestMapping("/mydata")
public Stream<OutputData> mydata(...) {
    return backend.readData(...).map(this::convertMyToOutput);
}
```